# How to resolve "403 Unauthorized request" error in SAP loadrunner script?

Tags: http-status-code-403, loadrunner

After recording a script of SAP site using loadrunner , while executing them we are getting "403 Unauthorized request" error for a request where we are passing the SAP ID.
We have done the correlations also . But still its throwing error

Answer (score 0):

Please define, "we have done the correlations also."

403 is a credential issue, related either to poor credentials or an expired session token which is not handled in your test code.